# Blocked migration to MathSE

Tags: bug, migration, closed-questions, vote-to-close

The following MO question [Why is $O(n;k)$ not connected, and has four connected components?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297985/why-is-onk-not-connected-and-has-four-connected-components) ([revisions](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/297985/revisions)/[timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/297985/timeline))

had the following history

- had a detailed answer
- (a) has been closed as off-topic (by a set $A$ of 5 users)
- had a comment (by myself) suggesting being reopened and then migrated to MathSE
- (b) was reopened (by a set $B$ of five users)
- (c) was closed (by a set $C$ of five users)
- was flagged, then reopened and closed again by a moderator.

The sets $A,B,C$ can be found in the edit history; we have $A\cap (B\cup C)=\emptyset$, while $B\cap C$ has cardinal 3.

That (c) resulted in a closure than a migration is quite puzzling. I thought it means that there were at least 3 closing votes (rather than migration); there was indeed one (as "unclear") when I voted to migrate.

The moderator (Todd Trimble) says that "*Ah, here's the deal: it can't be migrated (blocked from asking).*" What does it mean technically?

Comment: I suppose "blocked from asking" refers to the [question ban](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/post-ban/info) on the target site. It seems that in such cases the migration is not possible: [Block migration if user is suspended/question-blocked at destination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102293). (Perhaps on this basis, adding also ([meta-tag:post-ban]) might be reasonable...?)

Comment: I don't know the specifics (yet) about this case, but a user can be blocked from asking because of a negative reputation score, or being under suspension, etc. Some relevant information can be found here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/86998#86998 and here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151445/account-banned-from-asking-questions-despite-being-compliant-with-rules Some of this is automated by software whose precise algorithm is not publicly discernable.

Comment: The fact that the rejection of the migration is displayed neither in the [revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/297985/revisions) nor in the [timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/297985/timeline) seems unusual to me. Can somebody with 10k+ reputation check whether some information about this question is at least displayed in [migrations stats](https://mathoverflow.net/tools/posts/migrated/rejected) under [moderator tools](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/moderator-tools)?

Comment: I have also asked this question on Meta Stack Exchange: [Information about migration rejected because of post-ban/suspension?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309286) Maybe somebody will answer it and add additional explanation whether there was an easy way to find out that the migration was blocked/rejected because of the question ban.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I didn't see it in the migration stats.